# Linear and Relative Layout aligment

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am unable to get the below shown layout..can anyone let me know how to achieve this layout ?

This is what I have but unable to get the specified layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/someimage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#88FF0000" />

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtview1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#003399"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtview2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to get this as final layout:

[image]

Comment: Orientation for RelativeLayout? `android:orientation="horizontal"` remove that not required for relative layout

Comment: @Raghunandan, it is not needed and the compiler will just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `RelativeLayout`

You can remove the unwanted RelativeLayout with black background. (Just to differentiate i added another relative layout with black background)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Edit:

You can also center the text in `TextView` and use `match_parent` for the layout width and remove the unwanted realtive layout. Notice the change `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"` in the below code.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

snap

[image]

Comment: Good answer, however isnt  your relative layout in the middle a waste?

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal i mentioned that just to differentiate coz the whole background would be white. see the comment in my post. that's not in the middle its below `imageView1`(relative)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `layout_width` of all TextViews to `fill_parent`.

Note that your code should not even compile because the `layout_width` attribute is mandatory, and you don't specify it for the second TextView, and it also does not have a style attribute where it might be specified.

Answer (score 0):

The below hierarchy can also do what you want:

```
Linear-Horizontal
    Linear-Vertical
        imageview
    Linear-Horizontal
        textview
        textview
        textview
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a vertical linear layout where you put the image view in. Also put a horizontal linear layout in, where you place the textviews. Set the vertical height to wrap content and the horizontal to match parent.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/someimage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#88FF0000" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="right" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtview1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView2" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview 3"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtview2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```